# Matlab function (improfile) in OpenCV - Python 2.7

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, opencv

What I'm trying to do is generate two lines on a binary image (one vertical, one horizontal). Then return all of the row/column values along with pixel values underneath that line and place them into a python list.

In matlab you could do this similarly by running `improfile()` on a binary image where you set the binary image to have "10/255" pixel values by `im2bw(image,10/255)`.

Is this even possible with opencv in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV (module `cv2`) images can be handled as `numpy.array`s.

So, if you first want to convert an image into black-and-white:

```
bwimg = image > 10
```

This creates an array of True/False values depending on whether the corresponding element in `bwimg` is over 10 or not. The intensity scaling is usually between 0..255, if you have read the image from a file. (It may be other values, as well.)

If you then want to have the values on a horizontal line from pixel (23,57) to (86,57), you just pick the corresponding values from the array:

```
pixels = bwimg[57, 23:87]
```

Now you have an array of True/False values. If you'd rather have numbers, multiply it by 1:

```
pixels = 1 * bwimg[57, 23:87]
```

Vertical line goes similarly:

```
pixels = bwimg[2:65, 47]
```

picks pixels 2..64 (note that end of the range is excluded) on column 47.

Just a gotcha for Matlab users: Python array indices start from 0.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to look at these numpy arrays and find the x,y location of the first / last "True" values in the pixels arrays? I am just trying to find where the pixels > 10 start in each horizontal/vertical profile. Thanks!

Comment: @Spatial Pariah: There are several ways. If you have your profile in `v`, you get the list of all nonzeros (non-False) by: `nz=numpy.nonzero(v)[0]`. If you want to see the first one of this list, use `nz[0]`, for last one, use `nz[-1]`. (You may apply this to a non-BW image by simply using, e.g., `numpy.nonzero(x>10)`. This returns the indices for all elements greater than 10 in `x`.

Answer (score 1):

C interface to OpenCV has [`cvSampleLine` function](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d4e/group__imgproc__c.html#gad90886b00fecd146616555f273b592fa) that

> Fetches pixels that belong to the specified line segment and stores
>   them to the buffer.